# Scrollbar in Iframe ending before content. So is there a way to set scrollbar height to height of content

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, scrollbar

So, can some one help me here, there is big webpage which is getting cut around 70% as the scroll bar is ending

Code:

```
</div>
    <div id="divCustomDataPreview" title="Custom Form Preview"   style="background-color: #ffffff; height:580px; !important; display: none;overflow:hidden; " >
        <iframe  id='ifrCustomDataPreview' style="border: 0px; overflow:hidden !important;" scrolling="yes" width='100%' height='100%' onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="divFormCreate" title="Convert To Form" style="display: none;background-color:#FFFFFF">


function resizeIframe(obj) {
    var BrowserName=BrowserDetecting().split('#')[0];
    if(BrowserName == "Chrome" || BrowserName == "Safari")
        obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    else                
        obj.style.height=obj.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

Comment: What is the scrollbar on? why not make that element the height of it's parent?  That way your scrollbar won't get cut off

Answer (score 0):

I used a js function to set height and it worked. But my issue was with settimer as height being set before iframe is getting loaded:

```
function resizeIframe(iframeID) {   
    var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById(iframeID);
    var container = document.getElementById('content');

    iframe.style.height = container.offsetHeight + 'px';            
}
```